# Angularjs SPA and generating sitemap

Tags: angularjs, seo, sitemap.xml

Im wondering on practices to generate a sitemap for a angular spa application.

Basically i got a single homepage, and other pages where users can post various entries, kinda like a forum.Very simple.

Wondering what would be different in generating a sitemap for that as opposed to a normal non-spa site.

Also please notice that starting from may this year google is capable of indexing javascript generated pages.

http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.ro/2014/05/understanding-web-pages-better.html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [Stack Overflow: How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [Jon Skeet's Question Checklist](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist.aspx) to find out how to ask a good question that will generate good useful, answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the purpose of the above comment is - this particular question seems pretty clear (and common) to me.

Google can do a lot to index JS apps now but most of it is trying to be sensitive to lazy-loaded content. There are many sites today that load things like comment streams, sidebar widgets, and sometimes even primary content into an empty page shell as a separate resource. Without making specific statements about exactly what they do, what Google has implied is that they're pretty good at dealing with this type of thing now.

That doesn't mean they're going to actually exercise your app, and in an SPA the risk is very high that they won't discover everything you want them to do. This is an architectural problem that you need to take back to your data model, which you know better than anybody else. Your best result is going to come from using server-side code (usually in a batch job) to generate a sitemap.xml from your raw data schema. You can generate all the URLs you know your app will respond to and set the sitemap up to accurately reflect the way you want your app indexed.

Google can then hit each of those pages, and all you need to do is make sure that when they do, those pages will work without further interaction. That way they don't have to follow links within the app pages themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Within your website, use the hashbang or HTML5 URLS to point to the content--Google and Bing are smart enough to figure out that they're AJAX-generated pages.

```
...

  http://www.yourwebsite.com/#!/home
  daily

...
```

More can be found in here- https://www.yearofmoo.com/2012/11/angularjs-and-seo.html#make-a-sitemap-as-well